# неявный Intent для вызова Activity (Service) не работает в Android 5.1

Tags: android, service, android-intent

Есть сервис и приложение реализованы разными проектами. в Android 4 все нормально работает. При получении смс или нажатии кнопки в приложении 
выполняется:

```
public void onClickStart(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.kir.myapplication.service")
            .putExtra(KEY, STATUS_CODE_START);
    startService(intent);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onClickStart");
}
```

при `startService(intent);`запускается сервис, который выполняет нужные операции. Но при запуске на Android 5.1 приложение падает со следующей ошибкой.

```
 05-23 12:25:39.167 10539-10539/com.example.kir.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.kir.myapplication, PID: 10539
      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4074)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4069)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.example.kir.myapplication.service (has extras) }
      at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1801)
      at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1830)
      at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1814)
      at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:516)
      at com.example.kir.myapplication.MainActivity.onClickStart(MainActivity.java:63)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интент для запуска сервиса должен создаваться не так `new Intent("com.example.kir.myapplication.service")`, а так `new Intent(context, MyService.class)`.

Вам об этом намекают в сообщении об ошибке "Service Intent must be explicit". То есть интент должен явно указывать какой сервис он запускает, а у вас создается интент с действием "com.example.kir.myapplication.service", которое теоретически может обрабатывать кто угодно.

Если вам нужно запустить сервис из другого приложения и соответственно вы не можете указать его класс, то можно сделать так:

```
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName(servicePackage, serviceClass));
```

где `servicePackage` это имя пакета приложения с сервисом, а `serviceClass` это соответственно полное имя класса сервиса.

Comment: именно такую возможность исправить проблему искал. подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне указать явно класс сервиса, если он в другом проекте.

Comment: @x555xx дополнил ответ таким вариантом

Comment: **Большое спасибо, очень помогли! ** на 4.4 и на 5.1 все работает. Единственное добавлю, Android Studio по умолчанию добавляет в манифест  service с именем класса без пакета:      `   <service
            android:name=".MyService"`
поэкспериментировал с вариантами, у меня заработало только если в манифесте указать       `  <service
            android:name="com.example.kir.s001.MyService"` и в интенте для значения класса сервиса тоже указать класс с пакетом  -` new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.kir.s001", "com.example.kir.s001.MyService"));`

Comment: `<service android:name=".MyService"` абсолютно эквивалентно `<service android:name="com.example.kir.s001.MyService"` если имя пакета "com.example.kir.s001". Собственно первый вариант это просто сокращение второго.